# How to use MongoDB aggregation to find document based on Binary ID

Tags: mongodb, binary, aggregation

I'm wondering whether it's possible to use MongoDB aggregates (i.e. by using compass) to filter by a Binary value. In my problem i'm trying to find documents based on if they contain a field with a certain Binary id. I've tried:

```
 {$match : { FieldWithBinaryValues: {$elemMatch : {$eq : Binary('extrOROmZqRu3ToCFD/b2Q==', 3)}}}}
```

without any success (the field is an array of Binary ID's, thus elemMatch).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
{
  $match: {
    FieldWithBinaryValues: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $eq: BinData(3,'extrOROmZqRu3ToCFD/b2Q==')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.